# Finding the PGF from a mass function

Tags: probability

I'm stuck trying to answer this question.

Given the mass function for a random variable X, find the PGF: $$ G_{X}(z)$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X=k) = \frac{3}{4^{k+1}} , k = 0,1,2,...$$

I've currently managed to get it into the form $$3\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^{1+k}}z^{^{k}}$$

But cant work out how to get it to the answer given which is:$$\frac{3}{4-z}$$

Comment: Look up 'geometric series'.

Comment: Hint. $\frac{3}{4-z}=\frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{4}},\, |z|<4.$

Answer (score 1):

$$3\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^{1+k}}z^{^{k}}=\frac{3}{4}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{4})^{^{k}}$$ because $4^{k+1}=4*4^k$

Assuming $u=\frac{z}{4}$,  we know that if $|u|<1$, or if $|z|<4$
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}u^k=\frac{1}{1-u}$$

Therefore 
$$3\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^{1+k}}z^{^{k}}=\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{4}}=\frac{3}{4-z}$$